# How to customize incoming HTML emails from specific contacts?

Tags: email, thunderbird

Is there a way to customize incoming HTML emails from **specific contacts** using userContent.css?

I want to change the way messages from specific contacts in my address book are displayed. The users have chosen hard to read fonts.

Comment: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Junk_Mail_Controls

Comment: This is not junk mail.  This is from specific contact(s) in my address book. The users have chosen hard to read fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am looking to do apparently is not possible without some sort of extension support.  Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

[Font Settings in Thunderbird](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Font_settings_in_Thunderbird) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the way Thunderbird displays messages by using a [userContent.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserContent.css) file.

> userContent.css in the  chrome folder
>   is a CSS file that you can use to
>   change the way web sites and e-mails
>   look. This file does not exist in a
>   new profile. You can create it
>   manually.
>
> Note:  This file only affects your
>   Mozilla application's display (when
>   you are using a particular profile).
>   It does not actually change any web
>   page or e-mail message. For example,
>   if you use the file to change colors
>   in e-mail messages, it does not affect
>   messages that you send—so people who
>   receive messages from you will see
>   them using their own choice of colors,
>   not using your choice of colors.